# Merging 2 branches without involving master branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

We are working on 2 different product features on 2 separate branches on git, let's say feature 1 and feature 2, now both of them are in development mode and have been branched out from master at different points of time. We have a demo scheduled for the top management in which we would be required to show both the features, but we are not supposed to merge them into master ( as we are still in development mode ). Is there a way in which we can merge feature 1 and feature 2 into a demo_feature branch and take the build from the demo_feature branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of branching the demo_feature off of master, branch the demo_feature branch off of one of the existing feature branches, and merge in the other feature branch.